# Google Sheets evaluates only first condition in array in SUMIFS statement

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I found an example in Excel where one can use an array to set OR conditions. I want to do this in Google Sheets but I'm not sure how. Using the same syntax doesn't work.

SUM(SUMIFS({})
Excel University

Report

```
Sales   30,050 => formula: =SUM(SUMIFS($C$18:$C$28,$B$18:$B$28,{"Sales-Labor","Sales-Hardware","Sales-Software"}))
COS 21,136

Gross Profit    8,914

SG&A    2,054

Net Income  6,860
```

Data

```
Account Amount
Sales-Labor 15,050
Sales-Hardware  10,779
Sales-Software  4,221
COS-Labor   9,058
COS-Hardware    8,172
COS-Software    3,906
Supplies    256
Marketing   1,200
Trade shows 200
Telephone   299
Internet    99
```

If you pop the same values into Google Sheets and the same formula as marked above, you'll only get the value of the first criteria.

Source: http://www.excel-university.com/sumifs-with-or/

Comment: closest I can come up with `=SUM(QUERY(B18:C28,"select C where B ='Sales-Labor'or B = 'Sales-Hardware'or B ='Sales-Software'"))`

Comment: Or `=SUM(QUERY(B18:C28,"select C where B like 'Sales%'"))`

Comment: The situation I actually want to use it in wouldn't allow the 'like' expression. Using Query is virtually no shorter than just doing another SUMIF, which is what I've done as a patch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fairly simple solution is just to use `SUMPRODUCT` and `ISNUMBER(MATCH)`

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
  $C$18:$C$28,
  ISNUMBER(MATCH(
    B18:B28,
    {"Sales-Labor","Sales-Hardware","Sales-Software"},
    0)))
```

Or with `SUMIFS`. You can make the delimiter something other than an empty string to avoid clashes.

```
=ArrayFormula(SUMIFS(
   C18:C28, 
   FIND(B18:B28,
        JOIN("",
             {"Sales-Labor","Sales-Hardware","Sales-Software"})), 
   ">0"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the * wildcard within the SUMIFS formula:

```
=SUMIFS(B2:B12,A2:A12,"Sales*")
```